# Oracle scenario pattern matching and specified characters extract

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field of long text.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| S101 | Sentence : There once was a poor boy who spent his days going door-to-door selling newspapers to pay for school. One day, as he was walking his route, he started feeling low and weak.The poor boy was starving, so he decided to ask for food when he came to the next door. Sentence : The poor boy asked for food but was denied every time, until he reached the door of a girl. He asked for a glass of water,but seeing his poor state, the girl came back with a glass of milk. The boy asked how much he owed her for the milk, but she refused payment.Sentence : Years later, the girl, who was now a grown woman, fell sick. She went from doctor to doctor, but no one was able to cure her.Finally, she went to the best doctor in town.Sentence : The doctor spent months treating her until she was finally cured. Despite her happiness, she was afraid she couldn’t afford to pay the bill. But, when the hospital handed her the bill, it read, ‘Paid in full, with a glass of milk.’ |
|  |  |
| S102 | Sentence : There once was a king named Midas who did a good deed for a Satyr. And he was then granted a wish by Dionysus, the god of wine. Sentence : For his wish, Midas asked that whatever he touched would turn to gold. Despite Dionysus’ efforts to prevent it, Midas pleaded that this was a fantastic wish, and so, it was bestowed. Sentence : Excited about his newly-earned powers, Midas started touching all kinds of things, turning each item into pure gold. |

Every time the word "sentence" shows, we will trim the data from the word "sentence" to 50 characters.

There are multiple records, s101,s102,s103..etc.
Below is the output I am looking for

Output:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| S101 | Sentence : There once was a poor boy who spent his Sentence : The poor boy asked for food but was den Sentence : Years later, the girl, who was now a gr Sentence 4: The doctor spent months treating her un |
| S102 | Sentence : There once was a king named Midas who d Sentence : For his wish, Midas asked that whatever Sentence : Excited about his newly-earned powers, |

Comment: How is that different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338234/limiting-to-specific-length-from-a-particular-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting to specific length from a particular text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338234/limiting-to-specific-length-from-a-particular-text)

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice with no additional information, especially when you have 6(!) different and very good answers for it

Answer (score 0):

Apply numbers (1, 2, 3, 4...) as many times as word *Sentence* appears in your string. Take all 50-char substrings. Merge them using `listagg`:

```
select columna, 
       listagg(sentence, '  ') within group (order by pos) sentences
from (
  select columna, pos, 
         substr(columnb, instr(columnb, 'Sentence', 1, pos), 50) sentence 
  from my_table 
  cross apply (
    select level pos from dual 
    connect by level <= regexp_count(columnb, 'Sentence') ) )
group by columna
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tG3J4UPb)

Edit:

*Seems like the cross apply doesn't work on sql developer*

It's not SQL Developer, you have older version of Oracle, in this case you can join data. Tested in Oracle 11g, lowest version which I can access:

```
with 
  mxc as (select max(regexp_count(columnb, 'Sentence')) cnt from my_table),
  rws as (select level pos from mxc connect by level <= cnt)
select columna, 
       listagg(sentence, '  ') within group (order by pos) sentences
from (
  select columna, pos, 
         substr(columnb, instr(columnb, 'Sentence', 1, pos), 50) sentence 
  from my_table 
  left join rws on instr(columnb, 'Sentence', 1, pos) <> 0 )
group by columna
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BHdKOl1f)

Comment: Seems like the cross apply doesn't work on sql developer

Comment: What is uour Oracle version? And I see in comments that you asked this already, what is wrong with those answers?